# Why do I get a segmentation fault when I allocate memory for a matrix?

Tags: c, memory, matrix, segmentation-fault, mpi

I am working on an MPI program with matrixes. I need 5 matrixes in each process. When I create the 5th matrix, I get a segmentation fault.

Here are some screenshots:

Here it work, when the sPrevParts matrix is commented out
[image]

Here it does a segmentation fault! :s
[image]
Here again the segmentation fault...
[image]

Here is this part of the code (if you need the whole code, tell me, please).

MATRIX_CREATE FUNCTION

```
    /* M(m*n) as array of rows, call free(p) */
    void **matrix_create(size_t m, size_t n, size_t size) {
       size_t i; 
       void **p= (void **) malloc(m*n*size+ m*sizeof(void *));
       char *c=  (char*) (p+m);
       for(i=0; i<m; ++i)
          p[i]= (void *) c+i*n*size;
       return p;
    }
```

MAIN

```
    /* Variables for the partial matrixes */
    double **aParts, **mParts, **mPrevParts, **sParts, **sPrevParts;
    /* Gets the rows of the partial matrixes of each process */
    rows = sendcounts[myrank] / n;
    /* Allocates memory for the partial A matrix of each process */
    aParts = (double**)matrix_create(rows, n, sizeof(double));
    /* Allocates memory for the partial M matrix of each process */
    mParts = (double**)matrix_create(rows, n, sizeof(double));
    /* Allocates memory for the partial S matrix of each process */
    sParts = (double**)matrix_create(rows, n, sizeof(double));
    /* Allocates memory for the previous partial M matrix of each process */
    mPrevParts = (double**)matrix_create(rows, n, sizeof(double));
    /* Allocates memory for the previous partial S matrix of each process */
    //PrevParts = (double**)matrix_create(rows, n, sizeof(double));

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    /* Scatters the A matrix through all the processes */
    MPI_Scatterv(&a[0][0], sendcounts, displs, MPI_DOUBLE, &aParts[0][0], sendcounts[myrank], MPI_DOUBLE, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);        
    /* Scatters the M matrix through all the processes */
    MPI_Scatterv(&m[0][0], sendcounts, displs, MPI_DOUBLE, &mParts[0][0], sendcounts[myrank], MPI_DOUBLE, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Scatterv(&m[0][0], sendcounts, displs, MPI_DOUBLE, &mPrevParts[0][0], sendcounts[myrank], MPI_DOUBLE, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    /* Scatters the S matrix through all the processes */
    MPI_Scatterv(&s[0][0], sendcounts, displs, MPI_DOUBLE, &sParts[0][0], sendcounts[myrank], MPI_DOUBLE, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    //MPI_Scatterv(&s[0][0], sendcounts, displs, MPI_DOUBLE, &sPrevParts[0][0], sendcounts[myrank], MPI_DOUBLE, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < npes; ++i) {
        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        if (myrank == i) {
            printf("%d\n", i);
            matrix_print(aParts, rows, n, "aParts");
            matrix_print(mParts, rows, n, "mParts");
            matrix_print(sParts, rows, n, "sParts");
            matrix_print(mPrevParts, rows, n, "mPrevParts");
        }
    }
```

NOTE: This is being run by ALL the processes.

Could it be that I have used up all the memory? How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: You always want to start by looking at/sharing the stacktrace of all your segfaults. Also note that absence of proof is not proof of absence; meaning that when no segfault is raised, you can still (very probably) have invalid memory accesses. Please make sure to get your development tools (be it Valgrind, Visual Studio or what have you) to report all access violations.

Comment: You need to apply "binary search" for the problem. As print statements until you discover the ONE that causes the problem. Then start removing parts until you have a tiny program that still crashes. Post that program.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. The problem is in the Scatterv's. I don't know how to fix this. The matrices simply aren't scattered when. I removed some code and it works, but I need the commented out stuff. What's going on with these Scatterv's? Thanks again. :/

Answer (score 1):

The `void *` gives it away:

```
malloc(m*n*size+ m*sizeof(void *));
```

You never actually allocate your matrix, but instead only a 2D array of pointers which you then treat as an array of `double`.

1. Don't ever do that.
2. You are probably developing with a 32-bit run-time, where your pointers are only half the size of `double` (or some other kind of system where pointers are simply smaller than `double`).

Consider [this example](http://www.cs.hofstra.edu/~cscccl/csc145/imul.c) for a basic reference on how to work with matrices when using [MPI](https://surfsara.nl/systems/shared/mpi/mpi-intro).

Comment: Hi @Domi. Thanks for your answer, but I still don't know what's going on with my MPI_Scatterv operations. :s By the way, I didn't understand how to change the "void *" thing you mentioned. Could you please explain better? Thanks again.

Comment: To be honest, now that I look at it again, that is not the issue. I will probably have to retract my answer. From your question, it sounds like this is not your code and you do not quite know what you are doing there. Maybe you want to start from scratch, with a simpler version of what you are trying to do. The single `malloc` array actually allocates the matrix, and in addition, an array of pointers to each row. Consider this [Tutorial on Scatter & Gather](http://mpitutorial.com/mpi-scatter-gather-and-allgather/) and make sure you get the right data in the right places.